# Error in creating stored procedure in db2

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I'm creating a stored procedure in DB2, it first checks the existence of a table and if it exists, it first drops it and then try to create it.  here is how the code looks like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Schema.R ()
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
P1: BEGIN
DECLARE SQLCODE integer;
DECLARE table_exists integer default 0;


SELECT 1 INTO table_exists FROM syscat.tables WHERE tabschema = 'schema' AND tabname = 'table1';

IF table_exists = 1
THEN 
    DROP TABLE schema.table1 ;  


    CREATE TABLE schema.table1 AS (
    SELECT
         A.*,
         ...
     ) WITH DATA;
END IF;

END P1
```

But once deploying it, it fails and throws the following error message

```
Create stored procedure returns SQLCODE: -601, SQLSTATE: 42710.
Schema.R: 18: The name of the object to be created is identical to the existing name "schema.table1" of type "TABLE".. SQLCODE=-601, SQLSTATE=42710, DRIVER=3.72.30
The name of the object to be created is identical to the existing name "schema.table1" of type "TABLE".. SQLCODE=-601, SQLSTATE=42710, DRIVER=3.72.30
Schema.R - Deploy failed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the compiler sees that the table already existed *at compilation time*. Avoid it by using dynamic SQL for the create e.g

```
execute immediate('create table schema.table1 as ( select ...) with data');
```

Comment: this solution works, but why is that the case? should I always use dynamic SQL when creating a table in a SP?

Comment: As per answer, the compiler sees 'CREATE TABLE...' and also saw *at that moment* that the target table already existed.  During compilation the compiler only considers the current statement, i.e. it does not consider the previous DROP TABLE. You can either DROP table table *before* compiling, or use dynamic-SQL (which means the compiler for *that* statement will run only when you CALL the sproc).  Study this page until you understand it:  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.embed.doc/doc/c0005785.html